# use http to run query on remote sql db

Tags: php, mysql, http

I'm trying to connect to a sql db through php but it seems that my hosting provider has blocked access to connect to remote db's so I've been told to use http and "parse a key" to my other hosting account (with a different hosting provider) and run the mysql queries from there and then send the data back to the original.

I need to connect to the db and check for certain info in certain rows. Then by using the `if` function, processing different code depending on what come back from the db (if the info is correct and is in the correct row, process x code and if the info is not correct in the db, process y code.)

^^thats the query i'm trying to run^^

I have it all working other then the actual connecting to the db part as my hosting provider has blocked it. They told me to use http (as explained above) but i have no idea how to do so.

Can anyone explain (in English please) how i would use http to do something like this? Or better, an easier solution?

I cant change hosting providers....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CURL to request that php page on another server and then process the response.

Example of creating curl request

```
$encoded = ''; // include GET variables foe example. POST will be similar
foreach($_GET as $name => $value) {
  $encoded .= urlencode($name).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
}
// chop off last ampersand
$encoded = substr($encoded, 0, strlen($encoded)-1)
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "myOtherHostThatBlockedMysqlAccess.com/mysqlPage.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $encoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

So - what we do in the previous example - we request mysqlPage.php on the server that has access to your Mysql db. In that page - you'll have to put your Mysql access logic.
After you retrieve records from db  - youll probably end up with some array like $someDbArray- you can serialize this array and simply echo it out:

```
echo serialize($someDbArray);
```

Whatever you echo out will be available to you inside of the $output variable that is the CURL output. So you can simply retireve your array like this:

```
$myDataArray = unserialize(output);
```

However - if you ask me - the best solution will be to get a hosting that doesn't limit access from anywhere. I assume you're using shared hosting? I'd switch to at least VPN or dedicated server. I mean - either way you go - via REST or CURL - latency will be tremendous. Also - I'm not sure what kind of data you'll be transfering but think of a security. You'll have to use https at the very least.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. So how would i go about using this with mysql fb queries. Sorry, i'm completely new to http. Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: Yeah i know i should switch, but the thing is, i'm working on a wordpress theme so this theme will be distributed out to many people and its target market is people that use the same hosting as i do.

Comment: I don't bean to be a buzzkill, but Db logic doesn't belong in a theme.

Comment: The reason for connecting to the DB is to just simply verify customer information and get values for variables that are echoed in certain links.

Answer (score 0):

Better you build some REST service in your remote site. That way, it can provide a secure and convinience data-mining (read/write) with standard HTTP mechanism.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. How would i go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you need the whole overview of it, read it directly from its founder (Roy Fielding) here : http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm. But if you need to read some newbie introduction, you can see the simple one : http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

If you can run a daemon on your server then give [DBSlayer](http://code.nytimes.com/projects/dbslayer) a try. It provides an HTTP interface for MySQL, among other things.