# how to use CURL to request a php page on another server and then process the response

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I'm trying to connect to a mysql db, but from another server and process all queries on that server and then send all the data off to the original server, using CURL.

I've been researching for hours and cant seem to find the right way to go about it.

so this is what I'm trying to do overall:

1. When somebody visits a page from server A, a request will then be sent out from server A to server B which will then connect to a db.
2. Once server B has connected to the db, it will take information from certain rows and fields and then send it back to server a.
3. Once server A has received the info, it will then echo out and etc etc...

Firstly, is this safe to do? It wont like open a door on both or even one server will it?

Secondly, I have no idea how to go about it.

An example code would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [use http to run query on remote sql db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848374/use-http-to-run-query-on-remote-sql-db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### On server A

```
$post_fields = array(
    'variable_name' => 'variable_value',
    'variable' => $variable,
);
$ch = curl_init('http://www.serverB.com/example.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

`$result` now contains the HTML of the page you have requested from server B.

### On server B

```
// pseudocode
$variable = $_POST['variable'];
$variable_name = $_POST['variable_name'];
$db_results = $db->getQuery('SELECT * FROM table WHERE `variable` = ?', array($variable))->toString();
echo $db_results;
```

### Is it safe?

This depends. Does the information coming from the DB need to be protected from public view? Obviously with the setup above the information is just `echo`d out to a page on server B. Was someone to find that page then they would be able to see the information.

If that does not matter then its perfectly save and does not open any doors (you own both sites right?) particularly.

If you need to protect against that then I suggest sending a token from server A to server B to authenticate that the correct script is attempting to access the information. Something like an API key, which you could pass as a header in your curl request and then get out and verify from `$_SERVER` on server B.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. The code you have suggested for server b ("$db_results = $db->getQuery('SQL')->toString();
echo $db_results;"). could you explain how that will get the info from my db and send it off to server a. Also, is it possible to pass a variable from server a to server b at the same time as this process is going on? As i have a variable with a value that the sql query will need to select a certain row, but this variable is placed on server a, so id like to pass it to server b.

Comment: `$db_results = $db->getQuery('SQL')->toString(); echo $db_results` is pseudocode to illustrate how you might get the results from the database and convert them into a string that can be `echo`d out to the page. You need to write this bit yourself to reflect your DB structure and your method of DB access such as PDO, ORM etc. _Original answer update to illustrate passing a variable through `post`_

Comment: hello, i seem to be getting this error with that code on server b: "Fatal error: Call to a member function toString() on a non-object in /db_access.php on line 6" where the code "$db_results = $db->getQuery('SELECT * FROM table WHERE `variable` = ?', array($variable))->toString();
echo $db_results;"

Comment: also, where you used "getQuery", shouldn't that be "mysql_query"? Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: That is [pseudocode](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=definition%3A%20pseudocode&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=73d4a0b2ffe0e558&ion=1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=73d4a0b2ffe0e558&ion=1&biw=958&bih=1058). You need to change it for mysql_query etc like I mentioned before.

Comment: hey. Sorry to keep piling on the questions but i was wondering if it's possible to post more variables but this time, from server b to server a instead. would i just put "$variable = $_POST['variable'];
$variable_name = $_POST['variable_name'];" on server A and "$post_fields = array(
    'variable_name' => 'variable_value',
    'variable' => $variable,
);" on server B? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: No. When the response is sent back to server A it is just plain text so you would need to parse it to get it back into variables. Perhaps you could have server B return a JSON encoded string, which you could decode on Server A. I really think this is something that should be dealt with in a new question though.

Comment: Hey, I'm having issues sending the data as variables from server A to server B. Ive manages to get the data back from server B as variables using JSON as you suggested but cant seem to get the variables to send to server B. There is no error but the data does not show up on server B. I've also tried sending it as a string, still nothing. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you update the `$postfields` array with your own variables?

Comment: hello. Yes i did. It's okay now, i have it working. wasn't echoing it out properly. Thanks for all your help!